# A problem on series with condition $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Suppose $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$ are both positive sequence and satisfy
>
> - $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{b_n}{n}=0$;
> - $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n\left(\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\right)=\lambda>0$.
>
> Prove (1) $\lim\limits_{n \to
>  \infty}a_n=0$;
>   (2)$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n<\infty.$

Notice that, for a large sufficiently $n$, it holds that $$\frac{b_n}{n}<\frac{\lambda}{4},$$and $$\left|b_n\left(\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}-1\right)-\lambda\right|<\frac{\lambda}{2}.$$
Therefore $$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}>1+\frac{\lambda}{2b_n}>1+\frac{2}{n}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Your two conditions imply that the conditions of  [Raabe's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#2._Raabe%27s_test) are satisfied:
$$
n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\right) = b_n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\right) \cdot \frac{n}{b_n} \to \infty \, ,
$$
so that $\sum a_n$ is convergent.

Or, continuing with your work:
$$
 \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < \frac{n}{n+2} \le \frac{(n+2)^2}{(n+3)^2}
$$
for $n \ge N$, so that
$$
 a_n  < a_N \prod_{k=N}^{n-1} \frac{(k+1)^2}{(k+2)^2} = a_N \frac{(N+2)^2}{(n+2)^2} \, .
$$